# Join dictionary item, keys

Tags: python, join

Please see below code snippet for join method (used Python 2.7.2):

```
iDict={'1_key':'abcd','2_key':'ABCD','3_key':'bcde','4_key':'BCDE'}
'--'.join(iDict)
```

Result shown as

```
'2_key--1_key--4_key--3_key'
```

Please comment why only keys are joined? Also the sequence is not in order.

Note - below are the individual methods.

- `'--'.join(iDict.values())` ==> `'ABCD--abcd--BCDE--bcde'`  ==> the sequence is not in order
- `'--'.join(iDict.keys())`   ==>  `'2_key--1_key--4_key--3_key'` ==> the sequence is not in orde

Comment: Please get rid of the trailing semicolons at the end of each line of code. This is Python!

Comment: `only keys are joined` that's what it does. use `items()` if you need the values as well. `the sequence is not in order` that's what it does, dict keys are not sorted. Use an `OrderedDict`. By `that's what it does`, I mean that this is the information you get when you bother to read the doc.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the question is `why does it behave as documented rather than how I would like it to?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python dictionaries are unordered (or rather, their order is arbitrary), and when you iterate on them, only the keys are returned:

```
>>> d = {'0':0, '1':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4}
>>> print(d)
{'4': 4, '1': 1, '0': 0, '3': 3, '2': 2}
```

If you need both keys and values, use [`iDict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

If you need ordering, use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: As of 3.8 (and even a little earlier), differences between ordinary dict and ordered dict are small.

Answer (score 24):

If you see the docs, you learn that iterating over `dict` returns keys.

You need to iterate over `dict.items()`, that it over tuples `(key, value)`:

```
'--'.join(iDict.items())
```

If you need to have key AND value joined in one string, you need to explicitly tell Python how to do this:

```
'--'.join('{} : {}'.format(key, value) for key, value in iDict.items())
```

Answer (score 5):

Iteration over a dictionary only ever yields keys:

```
>>> list(iDict)
['2_key', '1_key', '4_key', '3_key']
```

See the [`dict()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> `iter(d)`
>   Return an iterator over the keys of the dictionary. This is a shortcut for `iterkeys()`.

Both `list()` and `str.join()` will call `iter()` on their arguments to iterate over the elements.

Dictionaries are *unordered* containers; their order stems from the underlying data structure and depends on the insertion and deletion history of the keys.

This is documented under [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

> **CPython implementation detail**: Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.

Also see [Why is the order in dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-arbitrary)